# how to send post params using volley in android?

Tags: android, http, android-volley

Hello i am developing an app using volley in android.I want send some params to server using POST method But i don't know how to do it. I am using an activity in that activity class i have created a function for sending data to the server & getting the response,

Here is the code

```
    package com.example.healthcoach;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class HealthCreateAccount extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText et_fname, et_lname, et_email, et_password;
    Button btn_create, btn_cancel;
    String url = "http://192.168.1.32/get.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_user);

        initViews();

    }

    public void initViews() {
        btn_create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_btn);
        btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_btn_cancel);
        et_fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signnup_et_fname);
        et_lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signnup_et_lname);
        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signnup_et_email);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signnup_et_pass);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_create.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.signup_btn:
            sendData();
            Intent bsetup_intent=new Intent(HealthCreateAccount.this,HealthBasicSetUp.class);
            startActivity(bsetup_intent);

            break;
        case R.id.signup_btn_cancel:

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
    public void sendData()
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest str=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `StringRequest`'s `getParams()` method.

**UDPATE**

```
public class HttpPostStringRequest extends StringRequest {

    private Map<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HttpPostStringRequest(int method, String url,
            Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, String> params) {
        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
        mParams.putAll(params);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mParams;
    }
}
```

you can give your post params as a map(like key-value pairs) to the constructor

Comment: but i an not extending the request class?

Comment: You need to extending StringRequest， cause default implementation of getParams() in Request is just return null.

Comment: can you post some sample code for that like how i would be calling that class from my activity???

Answer (score 0):

just override getParams like this
its work with Json and String request

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "Androidhive");
                params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
                params.put("password", "password123");

                return params;
            }

        };
```